# How to send data from angular js to laravel 5 server

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, ionic-framework

I am trying to send data from angular js to server.. Laravel5 is running on my server.. I can fetch data using this but can not send data.. My code is bellow

AngularJs Code:

```
var request = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://www.myserver.com/json",
        data: { email: $scope.email },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        request.success(function (data) {
            alert(data.email);
        });
```

Server code :

route is `Route::get('json','JsonController@Json_login');`

Controller code is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Input;     

class JsonController extends Controller
{

    public function Json_login()
    {   

        $email = Input::get('email');
        $arr_Id_Status=array('email'=>$email);  
        echo json_encode($arr_Id_Status);
        }
}
```

But it giving me **null** alert

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using a POST rather than a GET request. You would need to create an appropriate POST route on your server but it's pretty much the same syntax on the client side, just change GET to POST.

```
var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://www.saadetera.com/json",
        data: { email: $scope.email },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data.email);
    });
```

Not used Laravel for a while but it would be something like:

```
Route::post('json','JsonController@handleLoginRequest');
```

Comment: I think that means you've not set the route up correctly. You need a Route::post that points to a method that you have defined on your controller. Check that your routes point to the correct methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, sending data will require a POST method while fetching will be using a GET method. Let's make the complete flow assuming you want to call a controller called **your_controller** and use its **your_method** function :

*This suits for Laravel 5*

Laravel Controller :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function your_method(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input(my_data);
    //Server side data processing here

    //Returning Json or anything else here
    return response()->json(your_answer_here);
}
```

Route :

```
Route::post('your_url', ['uses' => 'your_controller@your_method']);
```

AngularJS : Here is the chunk of code allowing data sending, it requires $http service. Let's assume your data is contained in the my_data object.

```
$http.post('your_url', my_data)
.then(you_callback_success, your_callback_fail);
```