# AngularJS : bind unpredictable amount of input in a form

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an application by ionic and working along with Laravel server.
The problem is, I have a list of items store in my server. In ionic application I will request for information of items from server to create a form. I have my code here,

```
<div ng-repeat="itemGroup in mydata">
    <div class="item item-divider nn-card-header">
        {{itemGroup.name}}
    </div>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in itemGroup.items">
            <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
            <div class="item range range-positive">
                broken
                <input type="range" id="{{ item.idgB }}" min="0" max="{{ item.max }}" ng-model="item.idgB" ng-init="item.idgB=0">
                {{ item.idgB }}
            </div>
            <div class="item range range-positive">
                missing
                <input type="range" id="{{ item.idgM }}" name="volume" min="0" max="{{ item.max }}" ng-model="item.idgM" ng-init="item.idgM=0">
                {{ item.idgM }}
            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

that `mydata` is this json data:

```
[{
    "name":"name",
    "items":[{
        "id":1,
        "name":"itemA",
        "max":2,
        "idgM":"m.3.1.1",
        "idgB":"b.3.1.1"
    }]
}]
```

My question is, I don't know how to get value from the input because I can't use jquery to find element. I have an idea that i will send the list of all unique IDs of items from the server to application. But I do not know how to get `ng-model` data by using string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to get the value from the input, you have your array of objects that you are looping:

```
itemGroup.items
```

and in your code you are binding each object of that array with:

```
ng-repeat="item in itemGroup.items"
ng-model="item.idgB"
ng-model="item.idgM
```

then I expect to have those values as `idgB` and `idgM` properties of each element of your `itemGroup.items` array

but since you are using:

```
ng-repeat="itemGroup in mydata"
```

the itemGroup(s) themselves are elements of the `mydata` array, then in your controller in order to access to those inputs data, you should have something like this:

```
angular.forEach(mydata, function(itemGroup, key) {
  angular.forEach(itemGroup, function(item, key) {
    console.log("First input value: " + item.idgB);
    console.log("Second input value: " + item.idgM);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. but I still have a question, is there anyway I can use a ````$scope.name```` while I have ````name```` as a string variable.

Comment: sure, $scope.name in your controller is bound to {{ name }} of your view

Answer (score 0):

Value from input is stored in model, so you don't need to find element,
you already use binding.

Here is help for how to use input in angular:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Comment: for Knighty Ra : Also, tell me where and how you want to use this input value.

Comment: i want to send all of values to server via ajax when click a button. I don't know how to do all these things. Thank for your help.

Comment: you have to post mydata back to server.
mydata will have all new values, but I don't know how to do this for "Laravel server" because I don't use it.
this is what you nead to check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454024/how-to-send-data-from-angular-js-to-laravel-5-server

Comment: or better is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422940/angular-js-http-post-with-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think question has allready been answered here:
[How to create an Array with AngularJS's ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model).

If you have any questions about if, feel free to ask in the comments